# No item in queue but there should be python threading

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, queue

I am working on a project that is a gui with a separate thread. When the user clicks a button a function is fired that sends data to the queue and launches the other thread. The other thread then gets the data from the queue and adds new data to it. Where the gui will then get that data and do something. But it gets stuck saying the queue is empty? Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
def click():
            if self.uN.get() and self.pW.get():
                self.q.put("LOGIN")
                self.q.put(self.uN.get() + "," + self.pW.get())
            else:
                self.q.put("eFi")

            con = Connect(self.q)
            con.setDaemon(True)
            con.start()

            time.sleep(1)

            while True:
                root.update()
                try:
                    data = self.q.get(False)
                except queue.Empty:
                    pass
                else:
                    print(data + "+")
                    if data == "Fcon":
                        tkMessageBox.showerror("ERROR!", "Failed to connect to the server!")
                    elif data == "nCre":
                        tkMessageBox.showerror("ERROR!", "A text field is empty!")
                    elif data == "Gcon":
                        for item in root.winfo_children():
                            item.destroy()

                        self.mScreen()
                    else:
                        print("?")

                    print('!')
                    break
```

Here is the other threads code:

```
class Connect(Thread):
    def __init__(self, q):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.s = socket.socket()
        self.q = q

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                data = self.q.get()
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            else:
                if data == "LOGIN":
                    self.login()
                elif data == "eFi":
                    self.q.put("nCre")
                    print("??????")

    def login(self):
        info = self.q.get().split(",")

        self.q.put("Gcon")
        print("GOD")
```

Comment: I see one if block that doesn't cover all cases, and if you get an exception you just swallow it up without doing anything. Those are two potential sources of information to help you debug this.

Comment: @BryanOakley I found out what my problem is. Having to loops both go through the queue at the same time some where pulling stuff the other was supposed to access so I created to queues and fixed the problem you stated and it was fixed! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was being caused by having two threads access the same queue one thread would grab the information before the proper thread was able to access it. To solve the problem I made two queues one for each thread.